# How do you fix a form page that is giving you a 422 error?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have been using Ruby on Rails for an app and have a long line of forms I am trying to use in the process. They have all been working perfectly but when I select submit after filling out all the information, the screen doesn't change on in 'inspect' it says the form is not assigned to any user.

I checked each form controller and I had something like this:

```
def create
    @crew_applicant_form = CrewApplicantForm.new(crew_applicant_form_params)
    @crew_applicant_form.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @crew_applicant_form.save
        format.html { redirect_to crew_applicant_form_url(@crew_applicant_form), notice: "Crew applicant form was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @crew_applicant_form }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @crew_applicant_form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here? I can send over the code html and model if need be

Comment: User seems to ba a parent of CrewApplicantForm. Then I would write `@crew_applicant_form = current_user.crew_applicant_form.build(crew_applicant_form_params)` (for a has_one relationship)

Comment: @Maxence while thats a bit more elegant he's assigning `@crew_applicant_form.user = current_user` which should work. But the question is missing any meaningful debugging information such as the request parameters, model validations and a simple breakpoint inspecting `@crew_applicant_form.errors` so its not actually answerable.